# Fiddler not working in any version of Internet explorer

Tags: fiddler

Fiddler works fine in Firefox but I cannot get it to work in Internet explorer. I tried uninstalling IE9 and it doesn't work in IE8 either.  I normally wouldn't care so much as i does work in firefox; however, i read in ie9 the issue with localhost is gone so I would like to take advantage of that.  I have looked around and cannot seem to find anyone with my same issue. Any thoughts on where to start?

Comment: What specifically do you see in the browser when Fiddler is running and you type http://ipv4.fiddler:8888/ in the browser address box?

Comment: There is no change in the "web sessions" window within fiddler when i ipv4.fiddler:8888 (or any other url for that matter).

Comment: The question was "What do you see in the browser" when you do this.

Answer (score 0):

Never heard about anyone having problem with Fiddler with IE.

The localhost problem is easily remedied.  One writes a dot before or something like that.

IE9 has a built in request/response viewer.  Not as competent as Fiddler but might work for you.

Comment: Yah you write a dot afterwards or use the http://ipv4.fiddler trick. The prob is I cant get it to work for any calls to the web much less the localhost using IE.  If no answer becomes available i'll just run chrome or something.

Answer (score 0):

I also did not see the traffic from IE in Fiddler. What worked for me was to click and hold the button 'Any Process' in the toolbar and drag the target icon to the IE window.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure IE doesn't replace fiddler mock response with the cached before one:

In IE11 you can press f12 to open dev tools and refresh the page (Ctrl + R) to see all the requests sent by the browser (in Network tab).

This is how the cached response looks like :

[image: This is how cashed response looks like]

You can turn on force getting responses from the server and not from the cache with help of the button on the top ("Always refresh from server" button):

This is where you can find it.

[image: This is where you can find it]

Answer (score -2):

People around the web have had a lot of trouble with fiddler. It turns out it is requiring a special certificate.

To fix it, go to tools>>>fiddler options>>>HTTPS and click `Decrypt HTTPS Traffic`, then click yes to both of the windows that appear.