# Cursor appears above contenteditable div with placeholder and :before attribute

Tags: css, contenteditable, placeholder

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="sud"></div>
```

```css
#sud
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position:relative;
}

#sud:empty:before
{
    display:inline;
    content:"hello";
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; left:0;
}
```

This works fine with all browsers, but with IE10, the cursor appears above the div. Can some one suggest solutions for this?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KX6BY/8/

Comment: you must remove the `position:absolute;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KX6BY/18/)**

**Disadvantage/Advantage of this solution:** This solution will hide the text on focusing the element which is a disadvantage but its more or less a good thing as many peoples use javascript to hide placeholder text on input fields focus.

**Details:**

1) Content shouldn't be a part of css, hence i moved the content from `:before` to `data-initial-content` attribute in html.

2) `.sud:empty:before` placed the initial content inside before only if the div is empty & when users focuses the div i set `:before` to `display:none;` using this selector `.sud:focus:before`.

3) No need of `position: absolute` in this solution.

4) Also added `overflow-y:auto` & some `padding` for usability & visuals.

Comment: By removing position:absolute, In IE browsers, cursor would appear after the value of content attribute. In this case, It would appear after "Hello".

Comment: check my updated answers ~ do test my new solution on IE as i am having troubles with **[IE fiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254266/fiddler-not-working-in-any-version-of-internet-explorer)** :(

Comment: @ImranBughio see [my updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayankcpdixit/KX6BY/48/). when you press enter after entering multiline text. cursor gets misplaced.

Comment: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KX6BY/49/) Instead of making `innerHTML` empty, I have used vanilla version of jquery function `empty()`, I have also added `cursor: text;` on `.sud` div. Now I dont know why does that work instead of innerHTML you would have to [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819922/empty-contents-in-contenteditable-div) to know